# Cannot stop tomcat7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I've installed tomcat7 on ubuntu (apt-get install tomcat7) and added some webapplications and config files, I start it with

```
sudo service tomcat7 start
```

and after 2 seconds it shows failure message on command line, but when I check the logs  everything is shown as fine and then it took 15 secs to load properly  because of the apps/configs. Though I am able to connect by HTTP the problem is when I try to srop it

```
sudo service tomcat7 stop
```

it promts ok and then it just remove the pid file, but doesn't kill the 8080 http connector.
In fact I can see the tomcat process via ps command.
On the catalina output files there is nothing, it seems still running.
Any ideas? Thanks

UPDATE
I noticed that after startup the catalina pid is not generated. So when I want to stop via shutdown.sh I get:

```
$CATALINA_PID was set but the specified file does not exist. Is Tomcat running? Stop aborted.
```

In setenv.sh I have these lines:

```
CATALINA_PID="${CATALINA_BASE}/catalina.pid"
export CATALINA_PID
```

Comment: Can you post the last several lines from the log file when the stop command is issued?

Comment: that's the problem: the last line of catalina.out is still: INFO: Server startup in 12691 ms

Answer (score 1):

Generally any service in Ubuntu can be managed as per your requirement by

```
sudo service <service_name> <argument>
```

**Service:** Name of the application you wish to perform any operation upon.

**Argument:** It can be Stop, Start, Status, Restart.

In this case you wish to stop Tomcat. So, you need to follow,

```
sudo service tomcat7 stop
```

Update: 
Another thing to stop the LocalHost you can do is by keyboard interrup. Hit CTRL + C to stop localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `sudo pkill -f catalina`  ?

Comment: thanks, I know how to kill the process but I'd like to do it in the proper way. I'd like to know what prevents the stop